# In Javascript numbers with only double zeros in their decimal place lost their double zero when converted to String ? Why?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, number-formatting, string-concatenation

I am developing a web app in which I need to concat some numbers as String format

One of the number need 00 at decimal place if it is whole number (ex 15.00)

But when I concat it with other number , the 00 got lost (ex 15.00 => 15)

An example :

```
const price = 15.00;
const period = 3;
const CC = 840;

const concated = `${price}${period}${CC}`;
console.log(concated);
const saltedHash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(`${concated}GhVT+6FySEgWVeUWCHLo2lks`).digest('hex');

post[0].saltedHash = saltedHash;
post[0].string = `${concated}GhVT+6FySEgWVeUWCHLo2lks`;
```

Now the problem is , the constant `concated`  contains `153840` instead of `15.003840`

Why this problem occurring ?

How to preserve 00s?

Comment: use a string ...

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry please explain more

Comment: You weren't explicit about wanting the `.00`, try `.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  ${price.toFixed(2)} ... now working . thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe why this problem happen ? it's good if I get an explanation and also useful to others

Comment: ...because `15.00.toString()` is just `"15"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), something like:

```
const concated = `${price.toFixed(2)}${period}${CC}`;
```

```js
const price = 15.00;
const period = 3;
const CC = 840;

const concated = `${price.toFixed(2)}${period}${CC}`;
console.log(concated);
```

The issue is that when you use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) it converts the number to string, i.e. `String(15) === "15"`, whereas when you do `15..toFixed(2)` it "returns a string representing a number in fixed-point notation".

Thus, `15..toFixed(2) === "15.00"`, i.e. `typeof 15.00.toFixed(2) === "string"`

Comment: why this problem happen ? it's good if I get an explanation and also useful to others